# ¿como usar el middleware auth de laravel con una tabla ya creada ? laravel 8

Tags: laravel, login, session, encriptación, auth

Mi login funciona bien mientras no tenga el middleware auth, al agregarlo solo me direcciona al mismo login, el problema que me encontre fue que el campo contraseña no esta encriptada entonces agrege un asesor para cuando la reciba la encripte
mi user.php

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
protected $table = 'dbo.seguridad_usuarios';
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'id_usuario',
    'password',
];
public function getpasswordAttribute($value)
{
    return   $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($value);

}
```

}

mi controlador loginController
por medio de los returns logre ver que llega hasta cuando direcciona a menu, es cuando vuelve a cargar el login, las contraseñas son correctas

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Session\SessionManager;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class LoginController extends Controller
 {
 public function index()
 {
    return view('login');
 }

 public function login(Request $request, Redirector $redirect)
 {
 $user = User::where('id_usuario',$request->usuario)->first();

 if(Hash::check($request->password, $user->password))
 {

    Auth::login($user);
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    
    return redirect()->name('menu')->with('user',$user);
 }
  }
```